# Trouble getting a html file to show in Django App

Tags: python, html, django, mongoengine

In my `views.py` file I have this currently

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse 
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404, render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.views.generic.base import View, TemplateView
from models import *
from forms import *

class test(TemplateView):
    def test(request):
        return HttpResponse("test")

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ["myapp/test.html"]
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from views import test

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'$', test.as_view(), name='test'),
)
```

`test.html`

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block content %}
   <P> HELLO </P>
{% endblock %}
```

Except nothing shows up when the site loads up!

The index.html file loads fine as the html file i am loading up is extending that. But as I click the button that is connected to the url 'test' in urls.py nothing updates. The text.html file just has the text "hello world".

Comment: check server log files.

Comment: Nothing wrong there, checking the error_log file under /private/var/log/apache2

Comment: What does index.html look like? Does it have a "content" block?

Comment: Yes I do, I added the html file to the main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `urls.py`, you need to properly import your view:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from yourapp.views import test

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'$', test.as_view(), name='test'),
)
```

In your views, you need to fix your class, thus:

```
class test(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'myapp/test.html'
```

You should not use [`get_template_names`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names)

If this is really all you are trying to do (that is, render a template), then you can import TemplateView directly in your urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
# from yourapp.views import test
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='myapp/test.html'), name='test'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your view like this:

```
class Test(TemplateView):
    template_name = "myapp/test.html"
```

This is the recommended way to set the template name.

Comment: Not working. Is it normal that if in the urls.py file, url(r'^newpage/', Test.as_view()), if I make a new page like that it hits me with a server 500 error page? When I access that page directly in the browser after. Because I now feel that my django project is not "entering" the views.py file. Something is blocking it between the urls.py and the views.py...

Comment: and what does the error say? do you have DEBUG=True?

Comment: Yeah, but there is no error, just blank. Not even a internal server error. Sorry for replying late, internet here is going down at the ISP.

Comment: Oh I didn't understand what you were reffering to at first. for the server 500 error page I get this: "test is not a valid ObjectId" when I set the debug to true.

Comment: And does it give you a traceback?